# How to return JSON array in container object

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have the following Asp.Net 4.5 Web Api method:

```
public IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> GetExtAllStations()
{
     RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client client = new RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client();
     IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> results = client.GetExtAllStations();
     return results;
}
```

This returns the following JSON results:

[{POINT_X: -81.0410610591,POINT_Y: 34.1831858023,TABLE_NAME: "Cedar Creek"},{POINT_X: -80.7653777161,POINT_Y: 33.8641198907,TABLE_NAME: "Gadsden"}]

What I need to return is:

{Station_Coordinates: [{POINT_X: -81.0410610591,POINT_Y: 34.1831858023,TABLE_NAME: "Cedar Creek"},{POINT_X: -80.7653777161,POINT_Y: 33.8641198907,TABLE_NAME: "Gadsden"}]}

As I am very new to these technologies, I would appreciate suggestions as to how this could be achieved. If possible, specific recommended changes to the above code would be helpful.

Thank you

To improve the formatting in my response to @L.B comment below I am re-posting it:

```
public IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> GetExtAllStations()
    {
        RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client client = new RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client();
        StationCoordinates coordinates = new StationCoordinates();
        IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> results = client.GetExtAllStations();
        coordinates.Station_Coordinates = results;
        return coordinates;
    }

    class StationCoordinates
    {
        public IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> Station_Coordinates { set; get; }
    }
```

I am now receiving:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'RCWindsExtSvc.Controllers.RCWindsExtSvcController.StationCoordinates' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) - I would suspect improper usage on my part.

Thank you again in advance.

Update:

The code has been modified to reflect Moby Disk's comment as below:

```
public IEnumerable<StationCoordinates> GetExtAllStations()
    {
        RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client client = new RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client();
        StationCoordinates coordinates = new StationCoordinates();
        //IEnumerable<coordinates> results = client.GetExtAllStations();
        IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> results = client.GetExtAllStations();
        coordinates.Station_Coordinates = results;

        return coordinates;
    }

    class StationCoordinates
    {
        public IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> Station_Coordinates { set; get; }
    }
```

The error code remains:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'RCWindsExtSvc.Controllers.RCWindsExtSvcController.StationCoordinates' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Create a class with a property `public IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> Station_Coordinates {set; get;}` and return it.

Comment: Thank you, L.B - my problem now lies in the usage (again, newness to the technologies).  My code is as follows:

Comment: @L.B : sorry for the formatting.  The error is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'RCWindsExtSvc.Controllers.RCWindsExtSvcController.StationCoordinates' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RCWindsExtSvc.RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: It looks like you did not update the return type of the function.  Shouldn't it be public StationCoordinates GetExtAllStations() { ... }

Comment: @Moby Disk : I have modified the code per your suggestion and I have reposted the code and error result as above.  Thank you.

Comment: It still says public IEnumerable<StationCoordinates> GetExtAllStations() instead of public StationCoordinates GetExtAllStations()

Comment: @Moby Disk - thank you again - I think that I have been looking at the code too long.  Upon properly applying your suggestion I received the error: 'Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method'. I then modified the StationCoordinates class to public, which allowed me to compile and execute the code. The returned results are identical to the original issue - no container object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L.B.'s answer seems to work just fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Server.Controllers
{
    public class TempController : ApiController
    {
        public StationCoordinates GetExtAllStations()
        {
            RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client client = new RCWindsWCFService.Service1Client();
            StationCoordinates coordinates = new StationCoordinates();
            IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> results = client.GetExtAllStations();
            coordinates.Station_Coordinates = results;
            return coordinates;
        }

        public class StationCoordinates
        {
            public IEnumerable<RCWindsWCFService.uspGetAllStationsResult> Station_Coordinates { set; get; }
        }

    }
}

namespace RCWindsWCFService
{
    public class uspGetAllStationsResult
    {
        public double POINT_X { get; set; }
        public double POINT_Y { get; set; }
        public string TABLE_NAME { get; set; }
    }

    public class Service1Client
    {
        public IEnumerable<uspGetAllStationsResult> GetExtAllStations()
        {
            return new List<uspGetAllStationsResult>()
            {
                new uspGetAllStationsResult() {POINT_X= -81.0410610591,POINT_Y= 34.1831858023,TABLE_NAME= "Cedar Creek"},
                new uspGetAllStationsResult() {POINT_X= -80.7653777161,POINT_Y= 33.8641198907,TABLE_NAME= "Gadsden"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON output from the above is:

> {"Station_Coordinates":[{"POINT_X":-81.0410610591,"POINT_Y":34.1831858023,"TABLE_NAME":"Cedar
>   Creek"},{"POINT_X":-80.7653777161,"POINT_Y":33.8641198907,"TABLE_NAME":"Gadsden"}]}

Which I believe is what you wanted.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct and I cannot thank you enough for your perseverance!  With your simulation code I can now isolate what is peculiar about my environment - Thanks again to you and L.B.